# IntelliJ does not see error but compiler does when using RX and lambdas?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, lambda

Hi I have the following code...

```
Flowable.fromIterable(records.records())
    .flatMap(record -> {
        return consume(record);
    })
    .doOnError(t -> t.printStackTrace()) <--- Compiler complains about this
    .onErrorResumeNext(Flowable.empty())
    .doOnTerminate(() -> {
        ...
    }).subscribe();
```

And...

```
public abstract Flowable consume(ConsumerRecord<String, String> record);
```

With the above IntelliJ doesn't complain of any errors. But the moment I build the code, I get...

```
Error:(71, 50) java: cannot find symbol
    symbol:   method printStackTrace()
    location: variable t of type java.lang.Object
```

If I put...

```
public abstract Flowable<?> consume(ConsumerRecord<String, String> record);
```

Then it builds and runs fine. So I guess the type information is lost somehow?

**Update**
The application is run through the Gradle run task within Intellij. And clarification the IntelliJ editor/auto complete DOES NOT think it's an error.

Comment: Are you building with IDEA or Maven/Gradle?

Comment: I'm building through Gradle when I run the java application run task.

Comment: check the Gradle JDK version, I'd say 1.8 is the minimum. Then reimport, build and run

Comment: Where and how? In build.gradle I have sourceCompatibility = '1.8' and when running java -version in my mac command line I get... 1.8.0_131

Comment: In IntelliJ settings, search for Gradle

Comment: I just tried with version rxjava:2.2.6 - everything fine here. Java 8.

Comment: Gradle JVM points to 1.8.0_131 the RX version I'm using through the dependency tree if not mistaken is... 2.1.9

Comment: So it only works if my abstract methods indicates unbounded wildcard <?>

Comment: Yes! Just tried that and it doesn't even compile. I'm on 2019.1 EAP

Comment: I think it does need the type invariant. Raw generics do not maintain that

Comment: Ok so there's an issue with the IntelliJ editor, because it think's it's ok.

Comment: Try upgrading to 2019.1 EAP. It's pretty stable already

Comment: Yep! Thanks. I was on 2018. Will try 2019 soon also.

Answer (score 0):

As per the comments above. Needed to upgrade from IntelliJ 2017 to at least 2018/2019. Now the editor sees it as an error.